# Creating an Docusign envelope from an external file with Rest API

Tags: docusignapi

I want to create a envelope in Docusign from an external source. I am having the external file URL (a PDF or DOC). So does the API support like I will give an external URL and it will upload it to docusign by creating a new envelope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to add a file to a DocuSign Envelope, you need to specify the document bytes in the API request.  It's not possible to simply specify the URL in the request and have DocuSign read the file automatically using the URL.

Using the REST API, there are a couple of ways to supply the document bytes in the Create Envelope API request -- the simpliest way is to include the base64-encoded byte stream in the **documentBase64** property under the document object.  See the REST API Guide for further details  (https://10226ec94e53f4ca538f-0035e62ac0d194a46695a3b225d72cc8.ssl.cf2.rackcdn.com/rest-api-guide-v2.pdf).